# Set Windows mouse cursor size Win 10 GPO

Tags: registry, mouse, gpo

I'm trying to set the mouse cursor size at logon and keep users from changing it. I have tried using a GPO with these settings.

USER CONFIG > ADMIN TEMPLATE > CONTROL PANEL > PERSONALIZATION > PREVENT CHANGING MOUSE POINTERS

And then adding these registry values
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\CursorBaseSize v:20

When the user logs on it adjusts the cursor, but if they change it the policy will not reset the cursor size. Also even thought the policy says it prevents changing the cursor sizer, users can still slide the slider and enlarge or shrink the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the users from changing the cursors, enable below policy:
Please note, the policy applies this a reg key and you should check for below reg key on the machines first:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization\NoChangingMousePointers

> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control
> Panel\Personalization\Prevent changing mouse pointers

Then, set the cursor to what you want from GPP side:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors

(Default) string (REG_SZ) needs to be updated to one of the names, so it sets the cursor to that "theme":

- leave blank for None
- Magnified
- Windows Black (extra large)
- Windows Black (large)
- Windows Black
- Windows Default (extra large)
- Windows Default (large)
- Windows Default
- Windows Inverted (extra large)
- Windows Inverted (large)
- Windows Inverted
- Windows Standard (extra large)
- Windows Standard (large)

To customize individual pointers, modify the following string values:

- Arrow - pointer for Normal Select
- Help - pointer for Help Select
- AppStarting - pointer for Working in Background
- Wait - pointer for Busy
- Crosshair - pointer for Precision Select
- IBeam - pointer for Text Select
- NWPen - pointer for Handwriting
- No - pointer for Unavailable
- SizeNS - pointer for Vertical Resize
- SizeWE - pointer for Horizontal Resize
- SizeNWSE - pointer for Diagonal Resize 1
- SizeNESW - pointer for Diagonal Resize 2
- SizeAll - pointer for Move
- UpArrow - pointer for Alternate Select
- Hand - pointer for Link Select

Double-click on any of the expandable strings then type in the full path of the .ani or .cur file you want to use for the pointer and click OK

You should test this on your machine from GUI side as well. have a look at your registry on the test machine, then apply the same from GPP side of your GPMC/AGPM.

**a reboot is required for above changes to take effects.**

Comment: Sadly this did not work :(

Comment: Let's apply the setting and run RSOP on the device or from your GPMC/AGPM.
Please save the HTML file as text and then copy/paste the text content here for review. THX!